# How to debug the preview in Xcode 13 or later

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I can't work out how to debug a preview in Xcode 13.

[image: preview]

Documentation for Xcode 11 and Xcode 12 has conflicting advice like

- right click the run button and you'll get a menu
- control/command/option click run
- long click the run

I've tried it all - and put breakpoints on almost every line of code in my preview / view / init functions - and however I hit run, it just... runs...  - so I see the preview, but no breakpoints are hit - no print statements come out in the console - no cool expanded ui display appears - and no menus appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: Previews ignore your breakpoints and print statements... as the name suggests, they are "preview"s (not your real app)

Comment: "right click the run button" that probably refers to the run button at the top-left of Xcode, which builds and runs your app on the simulator/a real device.

Comment: I can see in the documentation for Xcode 11 that it's possible to debug a preview - and there are all sorts of cool tools available when you do, like a 3d exploded view of your site showing which controls come from which object - just can't see how to get in that mode

Comment: The 3D exploded view works not in the preview, but once you actually run your app... it's called the "Debug View Hierarchy"

Comment: well - this is the page I've been looking at: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8vkqn3ih. - which clearly shows it is available for previews.... but the buttons they click on in the documentation don't exist anymore in Xcode 12 or 13.

Comment: The button is there on Xcode 12 but not on 13. My guess is they'll add it back in soon in a later beta. For now you just have to build or use 12.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like Apple has chosen to remove the ability to debug Xcode Previews in Xcode 13 with no guidance as to if/when it will be brought back.

> Hi,
> The ability to use a debugger for previews has unfortunately been removed. > As you pointed out, the workaround is to run the app in the simulator.
> Sorry for any inconvenience caused!
>
> Posted 1 month ago by Frameworks Engineer  

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683773

Comment: In Xcode 14.0 beta (14A5228q), I can successfully attach a debugger to SwiftUI preview processes.

Comment: What's the name of the preview process?

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the Debugger to the Preview Process like explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes)

> **Deprecations**
> Xcode 13 no longer includes a menu item in the Previews
> canvas for debugging a preview. Instead, use the Debug > Attach to
> Process menu item to attach the debugger to your previewed app.
> (73981969)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me in Xcode 13.1.

Comment: But, what's ne name of the preview process? Attaching to the suggested app process doesen't work.